# Conditional statement in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to do a conditional statement on cypress to check if the login link in the header is Sign in or Account or a class and then click on it.

The if condition is not working.

```
cy.get('header').then((header) => { 

if (header.find('Sign in').length > 0) { 
    cy.contains('Sign In')
    .click({force:true})  

} else if (header.find('Account').length > 0) {
    cy.contains('Account')
    .click()

} else {
    cy.get('.navUser-item--account .navUser-action').click()

}
})
```

I expect if Sign in found then it will click else if the Account is available then it will click else it will check by the class.

[always doing the last else condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liEF9.png)

[there is Account text and still it applied the last  else condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXYr8.png)

[Another code structure and now it always apply the first condition no matter what](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYTqL.png)

Comment: What is happening that you do not expect to happen? & have you read the conditional testing docs? https://on.cypress.io/conditional-testing#Element-existence

Comment: i didn't understand what do you mean by "What is happening that you do not expect to happen?" & Yes i did go through the conditional testing doc

Comment: Are you getting an error? What's not working with the code you provided?

Comment: The following
If X, then Y, else if A, then B, else Z
my condition is A and it should execute B but no matter what is the condition it always executes Z

Comment: @ZachBloomquist i added some screen shots and i even changed the code. thank you for putting the time to help me

Answer (score 4):

The following code worked for me.

```
cy.get('header').then(($a) => { 
        if ($a.text().includes('Account')) {
            cy.contains('Account')
            .click({force:true})
        } else if ($a.text().includes('Sign')) { 
            cy.contains('Sign In')
            .click({force:true})  
        } else {
            cy.get('.navUser-item--account .navUser-action').click({force:true})
        }
    })
```