# How to write a conditional to check if a page link/button is visible to click()

Tags: javascript, angular, cypress

I am writing a Cypress test on a quiz page with a random # of pages. I am trying to write a condition in Cypress that will allow me to click on a "SUBMIT" page link if it is the last page, else it will click on a "NEXT" link if it is not the last page.

I have tried using cypress commands such as .contains() and .find() which does not seem to return a pass/fail response. I have also tried various if statements, but when I use these, I end up using cypress commands that either pass or fail, but do not route to any alternate conditional else.

//Clicks on submit successfully or fails the test. Never hits the else clause if not the last page.

```
        if (cy.find("button[data-cy=submitBtn]").length > 0) 
        {
            // SUBMIT button exists
            cy.get('[data-cy=submitBtn]')
                .click()
        }
```

Expected result will hit the else if the condition is met and trigger the command.

Comment: Is the button submit button on the page but not visible

Answer (score 4):

This should be the condition you're looking for:

```js
cy.get("body").then($body => {
  if ($body.find("button[data-cy=submitBtn]").length > 0) {   //evaluates as true
     cy.get("button[data-cy=submitBtn]")
     .click();
  }
});
```

I believe your question might be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145926/how-to-check-if-element-exists-using-cypress-io/56151893#56151893)

Comment: I got this error when trying this: CypressError: Oops, it looks like you are trying to call a child command before running a parent command.

You wrote code that looks like this:

cy.find("button[data-cy=submitBtn]")

A child command must be chained after a parent because it operates on a previous subject.

For example - if we were issuing the child command 'click'...

cy
  .get('button') // parent command must come first
  .click()       // then child command comes second

Comment: Can you update your code in the question with the current code? If you want to click on that button you have to get it first with .get()...Code I posted is just a condition to determine whether that button exists at all. If it does and condition is true, then you have to do `cy.get('[data-cy=submitBtn]').click()`

Comment: I see :) I've updated my answer as well. Updated code should hopefully work.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Sorry that I cannot upvote it due to my new/low rep :(

Comment: No prob ;) Welcome to SO :)