# cypress - do action until element shows on screen

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

I know that [Cypress is not big on conditional testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Element-existence), but coming from a selenium webdriver background, I'm very used to using this kind of logic in my tests.

I am testing a [KaiOS app](https://github.com/wikimedia/wikipedia-kaios) that instead of scrolling, uses page flipping similar to a kindle device to make it easier for the user to read.

Currently, since KaiOS is based on Firefox OS, the only way to use the app on a computer in a similar way to the device is to use firefox. The problem is that the page flipping when running the tests on cypress (even with firefox) is not working as expected so when we flip the page it doesn't go to the same page as it does on the device or firefox.

So, since I can't make sure how to find the element I'm looking for, I need to keep flipping pages and look for it and then interact with it.

I have tried [a bunch of different things without success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145926/how-to-check-if-element-exists-using-cypress-io).

What I need is fairly simple:

1. go to page
2. check for presence of element, if not present, flip page. keep flipping pages until it finds the element
3. once it found the element, interact with it

Comment: If think you could do that with https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-wait-until and then manually checking for the element presence with `document.querySelector` because `cy.get()` would fail the test if the element is not present.

Comment: I tried using cy.log(document.querySelector('selector')) but logs nothing...

Comment: https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-wait-until/issues/104

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've already replied in the [issues you raised](https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-wait-until/issues/104) but I'll write the solution here too to help other users.

Well, step by step, you need to

- go to page

A simple

```js
cy.visit('<your url>')
```

- check for presence of element

The simplest way is to leverage the exposed `Cypress.$` jQuery instance and checking by yourself if the element exists.

```js
cy.visit('<your url>')
cy.waitUntil(() => !!Cypress.$('#elementToBeChecked').length)
```

`() => !!Cypress.$('#elementToBeChecked').length` is the `checkFunction` expected by `waitUntil`, it returns a boolean and `waitUntil` retries it until it returns `true`.

- check for presence of element, if not present, flip page

```js
cy.visit('<your url>')
cy.waitUntil(() => {
  if (!Cypress.$('#elementToBeChecked').length) {
    return cy.flipPage().then(() => false)
  } else {
    return true
  }
})
```

the `cy.flipPage().then(() => false` is useful to be sure that che `checkFunctin` resolves to `false`. `waitUntil` will call the `checkFunction` until it returns `true`.

- keep flipping pages until it finds the element

Done

- once it found the element, interact with it

```js
cy.visit('<your url>')
cy.waitUntil(() => {
  if (!Cypress.$('#elementToBeChecked').length) {
    return cy.flipPage().then(() => false)
  } else {
    return true
  }
})
cy.get('#elementToBeChecked').click()
```

If you want an even more detailed explanation about why you need `waitUntil` for a task like yours, take a look [here](https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-wait-until/issues/75).

Hope it helps

Comment: now in "production", thanks! 
https://github.com/wikimedia/wikipedia-kaios/commit/7895c5d1b0ddb6c7e83b4ba15e8150aefc89cbac

Comment: Glad it helped 

Answer (score 1):

Try using https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-wait-until to perform actions on the page conditionally

Comment: from the documentation I'm not really understanding where to put the retrying check...