# Handle(Catch) the wait (timed_out) error in cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, wait, cypress

I recently faced a scenario where UI component(with XHR request `/get_data`) is getting loaded on a page after a certain amount of time(let say 10 seconds), and it's not automatic. So I need to reload the page(polling) after 1 second and again need to wait for the XHR request, this process is continuous till I get the request.

> If it was automatic call then `cy.route('/get_data').as('getData').wait('@getData',{requestTimeout: 15000})` would have worked

To avoid this I made a custom function(which is not working):

```
while (true) {
  try {
    cy.reload()
    cy.wait('@getLogs') //But here this ERROR can't be catched!
    return false
  } catch (e) {
    cy.wait(1000)
  }
}
```

**I am getting below error:**

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 2000ms for the 1st request to the route: 'logRequest'. No request ever occurred.
```

The above function could be worked if `wait()` could be caught! I know this code is not ideal but I am not sure about the more appropriate way.

Thank you

Comment: There is a 3rd party lib recommended for this scenario [cypress-wait-until](https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-wait-until). Not used it, but the concept looks good.

Comment: Oh hey the author has added some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60446878/4716245)