# Cypress- if statement - skip the part of test code if the element isn't available on the particular page

Tags: testing, automation, conditional-statements, rendering, cypress

This code works perfectly when there is a tile element present on the page, but I am trying to run the same test on different pages. So, a few pages don't have a "tile" element tag.
I am trying to find a way to skip this piece of code if the element isn't present. Thank you for taking the time out to look into it.  [HERE is the screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0qDK.png)

```
if ((cy.get('bx--tile') {
  .its('length').should('be.gt', 0))) {
    cy.get('bx--tile').each(($el, index, $list) => {
     let url = $el.attr('data-href');
     if (url) {
       let options = Object.assign({}, {url: url});
         cy.request(options).then(resp => {
           expect(resp.status).to.eq(200);              
         });
     }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Try the solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145926/how-to-check-if-element-exists-using-cypress-io

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome this using IF statement, as you might already know IF statement doesn't work directly. But we can use something like this:

cy.get("body").then($body =>  {

```
        if  ($body.find('g[class=nodes]').length > 0) {                      

             //this will help you to bypass and desired condition

        }


       else if  ($body.find('section[class=bx--structured-list]').length > 0){   

            //bypassing *Structed list*

       }


      else  {
          //code which you want to executive/run for default case 


      }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an example in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).  In the [transactions feeds spec](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/tests/ui/transaction-feeds.spec.ts#L213) we conditionally close a date range picker if the test is running under a mobile viewport.  Refer to this test and others in the RWA for examples of how to conditionally apply or avoid selections and expectations.