# Returning Boolean from Cypress Page Object

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to understand how do i return a boolean from cypress page object?

**Use case:**

> I am trying to check if an element is present on the page. If so,
> return a boolean.

Code:

```
class DataTable {
  constructor() {
     return this;
  }

  has(fieldName) {
    // HOW DO I RETURN A BOOLEAN HERE?
    return cy.get('.view-and-field-name').contains(fieldName)
  }
}
```

**Mainpage.spec.js**

```
const dataTable = new DataTable();
expect(dataTable.has(field.fieldName)).to.be.true;
```

I'd appreciate some insights on what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145926/how-to-check-if-element-exists-using-cypress-io), and according to [cypress suggestions for custom commands and page objects](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions/) I suggest the next [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax):

```
Cypress.Commands.add("validateIfElementExistsInDom", (selector) => {
    cy.get('body')
        .then($body => {
            expect($body.find(selector).length > 0).to.be.true
        })
    
})
```

And you can use it in the test like :

```
cy.validateIfElementExistsInDom(fieldName)
```

And a general return boolean function example:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("validateIfElementExistsInDomAsBoolean", (selector) => {
   return cy.get('body')
        .then($body => {
            return cy.wrap($body.find(selector).length > 0) //Cy wrap is needed so the function is chainable
        })
})

//in test code
cy.validateIfElementExistsInDomAsBoolean(fieldName)
    .then(boolean => expect(boolean).to.be.true)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `expect()` on Mainpage has already been executed internally in `cy.get('.view-and-field-name').contains(fieldName)`, so it is redundant.

If `dataTable.has(field.fieldName)` fails, the test stops there - it will never pass out a false value.

If you want `has(fieldName)` to pass out a boolean, you need to switch to jquery inside, e.g

```
has(fieldName) {
  const jquerySelector = `.view-and-field-name:contains(${fieldName})`;
  return Cypress.$(jquerySelector);
}
```

But it is much simpler to go with Cypress commands and use

```
const dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.has(field.fieldName);
```

Personally, I'd ditch the page object and just use the command directly in the test.

Answer (score 1):

`cy.get` is not a synchronous function due to the [retry-ability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html) strategy,
so there is no way to return `Boolean` directly.

If necessary, you can use variant of [should](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html#Use-should-with-a-callback) with callback.

In your case, a simpler variant with `exist` is suitable (or `be.visible`, possibly more accurate for your case):

```
class DataTable {
  has(fieldName) {
    return cy.get('.view-and-field-name').contains(fieldName);
  }
}

const dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.getField(field.fieldName).should('exist');
```