# cypress: How can manage the application flow, if the element xpath is not present

Tags: cypress

I have the following scenario:

if the element is present, i have to do one activity and if not present will do another activity.

```
  cy.xpath("//div[text()= 'button').its('length').then(res=> {
 
  if (res > 0) {
    return 1;
}
else {

cy.log ("Element is not present")

    }
 }
)} '''

if element is present = Code is working fine, 
if the element xpath is not present = it try to search the element xpath (//div[text()= 'button') and throwing the error as 'Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: undefined, but never found it.'

if element is not present, Is there any way, i can handle the code ,
```

Comment: Does your element appear under condition of user actions, or under condition of application state?

Comment: Yes , element appears according to application State. According to the availability of data the element will present. If there is no data present in the grid, no element will present.

Comment: I think this issue has been resolved in [this toppic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145926/how-to-check-if-element-exists-using-cypress-io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using xpath you can (sort of) make it conditional by wrapping the xpath selector with `count()`.

```js
cy.xpath("count(//div[text()= 'button'])")  // ok with async content
  .then(count => {
    if (count) {

      //return 1;  // not useful, returns a "chainer"
      // ...but you can perform the required test here, e.g
      cy.xpath("//div[text()= 'button']").click()

    } else {
      cy.log('not found')
    }

  })
```

The shorter syntax using built-in jQuery might be

```js
const exists = !!Cypress.$("div:contains('button')").length

if (exists) {
  cy.xpath("//div[text()= 'button']").click()
} else {
  cy.log('not found')
}
```

Note that this is a partial match to 'button', where-as the xpath syntax is an exact match.

**Also note** - using `Cypress.$` by-passes [retry-ability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html), so it should not be used where the text is asynchronous.

From [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$.html)

> This is a great way to ***synchronously*** query for elements when debugging from Developer Tools.

The implication is that it's more for debugging after the page has loaded.

The best practice is to try to construct the test and the app's data in such a way that you ***know*** that the button is present.

Comment: Thanks for details explanation. cy.xpath("count(//div[text()= 'button'])") : Throwing an error as is not a valid XPath expression. It may be due to  count text.

Comment: It works in my test, and I have exactly that xpath call. Version is "cypress-xpath": "^1.6.1" in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Also works here [xpath-tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Comment: This one [https://xpath.playground.fontoxml.com](https://xpath.playground.fontoxml.com/?mode=0&variables=%7B%7D&xml=%3Cdiv+class%3D%22mybuttton%22%3Ebutton%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A&xpath=count%28%2F%2Fdiv%5Btext%28%29%3D+%27button%27%5D%29&context=) has the xpath query and the html - let me know the difference to yours

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. With [Cypress.$](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$.html#Syntax), you can validate the presence of the element with the help of the length attribute and then do further actions.

```
cy.get('body').then($body => {

  const ele = $body.find('selector');

  if (Cypress.$(ele).length == 0) {
    //Do Something element is not present
  } 
  
  else if (Cypress.$(ele).length > 0) {
    //Do Something when element is present
  }
  
})
```

Comment: Getting same error, When the element is not present , It try to search the element  in the starting of the  code :  cy.get('selector').then(ele => { 
and throw an error as  'Expected to find element: undefined, but never found it.'