# function to return boolean to check if element exist in cypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

How can I write a function to return Boolean to check if element exist on UI in cypress.

I have the following code, it seems to work fine until I hit one element that I can only get the element using `cy.get('.I_am_selector')`.

When I use my function `isElementExist()` it always return false because `Cypress.$('.I_am_selector').length == 0;`

```js
export function isElementExist(selector: string): boolean {
  try {
    return Cypress.$(`.${selector}`).length > 0;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Cypress `cy.get()` has retry built in, so if an element is loading or animating the command will eventually grab the element.

But the jQuery equivalent `Cypress.$(`.${selector}`)` does not have retry. You could try to build some polling in your function, but it's a lot of work and why is there not a `cy.maybe(selector)` built into Cypress?

Cypress tests work best if you know what elements are present, there's a lot of documentation around it, but there's always edge cases.

The only way I've seen to do this is here [How can manage the application flow, if the element xpath is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921472/14783414), using the [cypress-xpath](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath) add-on and the `count()` function.

```
cy.xpath(`count(//${element}[@class="${selector}"])`)  // ok with async content
  .then(count => {
    const selector = count ? selector : defaultSelector;
```

---

You may be looking for the [jQuery OR Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263975/jquery-or-selector) which allows you to supply a default selector after the comma.

If the DOM is like this

```html
<div class="pick-me">one</div>
<div class="or-me">two</div>
```

This test will fetch `div.pick-me`

```js
cy.get('.pick-me, .or-me')            // jQuery OR selector
  .eq(0)                              // in case both match, take first
  .should('have.class', 'pick-me');   // first selector is used
```

But if the DOM doesn't have the first class,

```html
<div class="dont-pick-me">one</div>
<div class="or-me">two</div>
```

the command will return the default selector

```js
cy.get('.pick-me, .or-me')          // jQuery OR selector
  .eq(0)                            // in case both match, take first
  .should('have.class', 'or-me');   // default selector is used
```

Comment: in the `cy.xpath` how can I return the boolean type? so I can have something `const select = isElementExist('I_am_selector') ? 'I_am_selector : 'I_am_default_selector'` under my function

Comment: Modified the xpath example.