# Cypress: End chain conditionally

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I'm quite new to cypress, but I am wondering if there is some way to end a command chain conditionally? I know that conditional testing should be avoided in cypress, but I want try this out anyway.

**What I've tried**

I tried to solve it by passing in the chain to a custom command, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('ifExists', { prevSubject: true }, (subject: object, element: string) => {
    cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
        if ($body.find(element).length) {
            cy.wrap(object).end();
        } else {
            // something else
        }
    })
})
```

and also

```
Cypress.Commands.add('ifExists', { prevSubject: true }, (subject: JQuery<HTMLBodyElement>, element: string) => {
    cy.wrap(subject).then(($body) => {
        if ($body.find(element).length) {
            return cy.wrap(subject);
        } else {
            return cy.wrap(subject).end();
        }
    })
})
```

And just a clarification on what I want from this command. I want to be able to add it to a chain like this:

`cy.get('body > #specialThing').ifExists().then((thing) => ...)`

or this:

`cy.ifExists('body > #specialThing').then((thing) => ...)`

All help and advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt the jQuery OR operator shown here [Function to check if element exist in cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67393810/9622173).

You cannot it call using the `cy.get('body > #specialThing').ifExists()...` because the cy.get() will fail if the element isn't there, so this implies your custom command must be a [parent command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Parent-Commands) (no prevSubject).

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('ifExists', { prevSubject: false }, (selector: string) => {

  const orSelector = `${selector}, body`;    // note comma, if "selector" fails return body
  return Cypress.$(orSelector);

})

cy.ifExists('#specialThing').then((thing) => ...)
```

You may find it more useful to return `null` rather than `body` so that you can test the result more easily,

```
Cypress.Commands.add('ifExists', { prevSubject: false }, (selector: string) => {

  const result = Cypress.$(selector);
  return result.length ? cy.wrap(result) : null;

})

cy.ifExists('#specialThing').then((thing) => if (thing) ... else ... )
```

**Warning** this will inevitably lead to flaky tests. There is no retry in this command.

See [Element existence](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence)

> You cannot do conditional testing on the DOM unless you are either:
>
> - Server side rendering with no asynchronous JavaScript.
> - Using client side JavaScript that only ever does synchronous rendering.
>
> It is crucial that you understand how your application works else you will write flaky tests.

Using `cy.get('body').then(...)` ***does not give you retry*** on the element you want to test conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out the Cypress documentation on conditional testing, [in particular the part about element existence.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence) The tl;dr is you just need to search for a more general element that yields something that you can then assert on.

```
y.get('body')
  .then(($body) => {
    // synchronously query from body
    // to find which element was created
    if ($body.find('#specialThing').length) {
      // input was found, do something else here
      return 'input'
    }

    // else assume it was textarea
    return 'textarea'
  })
  .then((selector) => {
    // selector is a string that represents
    // the selector we could use to find it
    cy.get(selector).type(`found the element by selector ${selector}`)
  })
```